# Can't switchPath 404s, fails to capture wildcard route

Tags: url-routing, cyclejs, switch-path

Feeding this into switchPath

```
  const Routes = {
    "/": Home,
    "/login": Login,
    '*': function(){return {DOM: xs.of(<h1> 404</h1>)}}
  }
```

navigating to `/lossgin` will log that current route/path is "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with [switch-path](https://github.com/staltz/switch-path). (And nothing to do with [CycleJS history](https://cycle.js.org/api/history.html))

See this switch-path [issue](https://github.com/staltz/switch-path/issues/16) and this [pull request](https://github.com/staltz/switch-path/pull/24).

Simply put, the wildcard * does not get captured when route '/' is in use and there are no nested routes. For example:

```js
const { path, value } = switchPath("/lossgin", {
  "/": 123,
  "/login": 456,
  "*": 789
});
```

`console.log(path, value)` produces:

```
/ 123
```

**A work-around** is to change your `login` route to a nested route:

```js
const { path, value } = switchPath("/lossgin", {
  "/": 123,
  "/login": {"/": 456}, // <-- nested route
  "*": 789
});
```

`console.log(path, value)` produces:

```
/lossgin 789
```

[See code example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9lkvpqw76)

Comment: the nested route must remain at the very bottom of object or else everything below it becomes wildcard.

Comment: @janat08 Additional specified routes, such as, `/home` need to occur in order before the nested route, but root, `/` can be listed after the nested route.